# Understanding the Neural Network Output using a Custom Gym Env continuous boundaries

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, actor-critic

I need help understanding some concepts on neural networks while using a Custom Gym Environment.

```
self.action_space = gym.spaces.Box(low=np.array([0.,0.]),
                                   high=np.array([4.,0.02]),
                                   shape=(2,),
                                   dtype=np.float32)
```

I have set the `action_space` as a continuous action space. Where the first element has a bound of [0, 4] and the second element has a bound of [0, 0.02].

I have tested to make sure that a random action sample, `env.action_space.sample()` will generate variables between theses bounds.

```
for i in range(10):
    print(env.action_space.sample())
[2.874337   0.01467643]
[1.2939405  0.01185006]
[2.8685462 0.0141508]
[3.6843169  0.01945442]
[0.14828023 0.00132717]
[1.7021259  0.00837106]
[0.42704833 0.00118186]
[3.3209796  0.00849273]
[3.2173667  0.00427724]
[0.9189667  0.00806994]
```

So far so good. Now, I have initialize a state which is `env.states = np.array([0, 23])`. I will feed this into my neural network with a input of two variables, two hidden layers, and a two outputs (hoping the give me values within the bounds as mentioned above.

```
state = env.reset()  # [0, 23]
results = Actor(state)
results
tensor([-1.9830,  0.0177], grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)  # Output
```

So I am a little confused on why am I having a negative value. It seems like the first variable regardless on what values will always be negative. My activation function are ReLU, so I would assume be 0 or a positive value.

[image]

Bonus questions: How do you add standard deviation to your neural network output? To my understanding, the output should be a mean of the two action space values, but if I need their standard deviation, how would I approach this? Is it as easy as changing my output to 4? How does the neural network know?